# Amplify authentication configuration usage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am working on an angular application in which we are using AWS Cognito for user maintenance. We already have user pool and want to connect to them for signin, signout, user CRUD activities.
Have some confusion around few things:

- Do I need to use amplify add auth and push ? User pool is created by
  our BE cloudformation script. We do not want to use amplify to create
  user pool.
- Do I have to install full aws-amplify lib or just    installing
  @aws-amplify/auth is fine? This will significantly reduce    my
  bundle size.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, you dont need to use amplify cli to add and push auth, you would just need userpool id and client id on the frontend.
2. I dont see any big difference in bundle size by using with aws-amplify OR @aws-amplify/auth and /core using angular.

Note: Use source-map-explorer to analyze the prod bundle size